# how to highlight particular row in JSF datatable

Tags: java, javascript, richfaces

I am new to JSF. I need to know how to highlight a particular row in JSF data-table or a particular field in a JSF data-table. Please any one give me a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can use conditional coloring using a EL expression like this `styleClass="#{condition ? 'old' : 'new'}"`.

Comment: That is not as simple regarding rows in `h:dataTable`.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie how is it not so simple could you please explain ?

Comment: You must use `rowClasses` to apply style classes on rows, thus you need to generate a list of classes and so you can't use a simple EL condition.

Answer (score 0):

Datatable row can be highlighted when mouse move over it or when it is selected. There are different actions. Both of them are implemented in following code (RichFaces 4.3.x).

xhtml code:

```
<rich:dataTable var="rs" value="#{retailerAction.retailerList}"
    rows="#{referenceData.recordsPerPage}" rowClasses="oddrow, evenrow"
    onrowclick="dataTable.onRowSubmit(this, 'selected-dt-row');"
    onrowmouseover="dataTable.onRowMouseOver(this, 'gridmouseover');"
    onrowmouseout="dataTable.onRowMouseOut(this, #{currRow}, 'oddrow', 'evenrow')"
    rowKeyVar="currRow" style="width: 100%">
</rich:dataTable>
```

Special style is used for **selected** row:

```
.selected-dt-row {
    background-color: gold !important;
}
```

Other style is used for **row under cursor**:

```
.gridmouseover {
    background-color: #E4F7FD;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Zebra** styles:

```
.evenrow {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.oddrow {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```